# My do while loop is only happening once even though I have input the same value the second time. Why is that so?

Tags: java, while-loop, java.util.scanner

```java
Scanner sc1 = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter prime p value up to 32 bits: ");
        BigInteger p = sc1.nextBigInteger();
        while(p.isProbablePrime(1) == false && p.compareTo(BigInteger.valueOf(2147483647)) == 1);
        {
            System.out.print("Sorry your p value must be a prime and up to 32bits! Please enter again: ");
            p = sc1.nextBigInteger();
        }
```

So I entered a value that is greater than `2147483647`, my `while` works the first time but does not run the second time.

```java
Enter prime p value up to 32 bits: 2147483659
Sorry your p value must be a prime and up to 32bits! Please enter again: 2147483659
Enter prime q value up to 32 bits:
```

It skips to my `q` value when my conditions have not been met.

Comment: You only need one scanner

Comment: Because in a do/while loop the 1st iteration (eg the do block execution) is always guaranteed no matter what input you enter

Comment: you are comparing p.isProbablePrime(1) with false which is always going to return false.

And why one the first place you are comparing boolean values with == operator.

Comment: Why do you compare to 2147483647?

Comment: just wanted it to be up to 32bits @Adder

Comment: `isProbablePrime` with that value returns true.  So, your first condition (`! isProbablePrime`) will fail, and you'll never process the loop.

Comment: Ah. Then maybe you want to use `||` instead of `&&` ?

Comment: @WonkotheSane wait, is my logic wrong? i want the value to be a prime and up to 32bits, if not my while loop will run and ask the user to re input the value.

Comment: you want `not(prime AND <=32bits)` to loop; but are testing `(not prime) AND (>32bits)` (to continue in loop) - also suggest confirming documentation of `isProbablePrime`

Comment: @ZacEe  Yes.  This would appear to just be a simple bug.

Answer (score 1):

Try using the following code instead (eg get rid of the do/while) :

```
Scanner sc1 = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.print("Enter prime p value up to 32 bits: ");
BigInteger p = sc1.nextBigInteger();
while(!p.isProbablePrime(1) || p.compareTo(BigInteger.valueOf(2147483647)) == 1) {
       System.out.print("Sorry your p value must be a prime and up to 32bits! Please enter again: ");
       p = sc1.nextBigInteger();
}
```

Comment: yea I changed to this and it is still doing the same thing

Comment: See updated answer, I've changed && (and) to || (or) in your while loop

Answer (score 0):

DO loops will always execute once no matter what.
So your coniditon always evaluates to false (so the loop stops).
try setting it like this

```
public final long c = 2147483647;

while(!p.isProbablePrime(1) || p.compareTo(BigInteger.valueOf(c)) == 1);
```

thats for

```
do{
     //do stuff here
}while(condition to break the loop)
```

Comment: It is still doing the same thing though, my while loop runs once and after inputting the same value it skips my while loop.

Comment: Look at the https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html#isProbablePrime-int-Method reference try setting the certainty to different values it seems to be the time this method runs aswell (so the longer you have it run the more precise the evaluation will be)

Answer (score 0):

Can you use this?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner sc1 = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Enter prime p value up to 32 bits: ");
    BigInteger p = sc1.nextBigInteger();
    while (!p.isProbablePrime(1) || p.compareTo(BigInteger.valueOf(2147483647)) > 0)) {
        System.out.print("Sorry your p value must be a prime and up to 32bits! Please enter again: ");
        sc1 = new Scanner(System.in);
        p = sc1.nextBigInteger();
    }
}
```